# in2csv fail on JSON

Tags: json, csvkit

I have a small JSON file which fails to convert a data value properly. The value in question is the "id" field and the conversion produces 2016-05-06. I have a much larger file (same format) and it works properly.  Any help?

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "seq": "10457-g1AAAAPreJy90lFqAjEQBuCgFj2B4EOpUgRfXNyscWef9CbtTMZFZF3Brs96E3uT9ib1IMIaE2XpmynUlwkE8n_8TDIhRGtRZzFg0uvNfMakAloNGbPhR4E544ZloLP1ljEvgnxeZOZFDQW9lGW5XNRJiKfnlblrYiRZqtQj6rcr73CpayZNK3pg6bGOmZE80vwr0-xCv1X0q6XViDGJ_t46vId-v9C7iu5YegIEmIw90vxb5w0zxd4cRj9c-Z7lSUEEIP-1ueM_Hf_l-MbJ8iGmxDE8oP2343-u7fvuy6WaRqQf0P7o-Nvu25ZPATRA6JG4PAMPEEFw",
      "id": "20160506175330-3168-01",
      "changes": [
        {
          "rev": "1-8bda66017d962508e51ac5061557635b"
        }
      ],
      "doc": {
        "_id": "20160506175330-3168-01",
        "_rev": "1-8bda66017d962508e51ac5061557635b",
        "year": "2016",
        "month": "05",
        "day": "06",
        "hour": "17",
        "minute": "53",
        "second": "30",
        "imagebox": "18x94+428+180",
        "alchemy": {
          "text": "person",
          "score": "0.845535"
        },
        "visual": {
          "image": "20160506175330-3168-01.jpg",
          "scores": [
            {
              "classifier_id": "Mixed_Color",
              "name": "Mixed_Color",
              "score": 0.964822
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Stove",
              "name": "Stove",
              "score": 0.923713
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Archery",
              "name": "Archery",
              "score": 0.836994
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Dish_Washer",
              "name": "Dish_Washer",
              "score": 0.835787
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Barber_Shop",
              "name": "Barber_Shop",
              "score": 0.825716
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Full_Body",
              "name": "Full_Body",
              "score": 0.824954
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Musical_Instrument",
              "name": "Musical_Instrument",
              "score": 0.817304
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Beauty_Salon",
              "name": "Beauty_Salon",
              "score": 0.808518
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Clothing_Store",
              "name": "Clothing_Store",
              "score": 0.784035
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Distillery",
              "name": "Distillery",
              "score": 0.67477
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Sweet_Treat",
              "name": "Sweet_Treat",
              "score": 0.588916
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Beer",
              "name": "Beer",
              "score": 0.538915
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Store",
              "name": "Store",
              "score": 0.536244
            },
            {
              "classifier_id": "Yellow",
              "name": "Yellow",
              "score": 0.526932
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "last_seq": "10457-g1AAAAPreJy90lFqAjEQBuCgFj2B4EOpUgRfXNyscWef9CbtTMZFZF3Brs96E3uT9ib1IMIaE2XpmynUlwkE8n_8TDIhRGtRZzFg0uvNfMakAloNGbPhR4E544ZloLP1ljEvgnxeZOZFDQW9lGW5XNRJiKfnlblrYiRZqtQj6rcr73CpayZNK3pg6bGOmZE80vwr0-xCv1X0q6XViDGJ_t46vId-v9C7iu5YegIEmIw90vxb5w0zxd4cRj9c-Z7lSUEEIP-1ueM_Hf_l-MbJ8iGmxDE8oP2343-u7fvuy6WaRqQf0P7o-Nvu25ZPATRA6JG4PAMPEEFw",
  "pending": 0
}
```

Comment: Stupid me; add --no-inference

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `--no-inference`.